# Navigation jumps when I scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

How do I fix my header? I was planning to create a smooth flowing navigation bar but I don't know how. I tried reading some answers here but I just don't get it.

Here's my code:

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    jQuery("document").ready(function($){

        var nav = $('#header');

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 130) {
                nav.addClass("f-nav");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("f-nav");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.f-nav{ z-index: 9999; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please reduce value (130) and set the perfect value from top.